# ¿Como solucionar problema de "found 2 high severity vulnerabilities" al ejecutar "npm install live-server -g" desde la terminal de VS CODE?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Buen día, mi situación es la siguiente: descargue NODE JS(v16.13.1) y NPM(8.1.2) en mi PC. En la terminal de VS CODE ejecute el siguiente comando:

> npm install live-server -g

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo en donde se encuentra el punto rojo(dibujado) era donde me apareció lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo que en mi caso decía esto:

> found 2 high severity vulnerabilities

Y fue ahi cuando empece a preocuparme un poco ya que creía que las dependencias estaban corruptas o rotas o que ya no estuvieran disponibles. Pero después de un rato buscando como solucionar eso, esa leyenda de "found 2 high severity vulnerabilities" había desaparecido. No se si haya sido un bug o algún error en la instalación por el cual haya sucedido eso.
Asimismo ejecute los siguientes comandos:

> npm audit

y me salio lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

también ejecute el siguiente comando:

> npm audit fix --force

y me salio esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y bueno no se si los comandos que ejecute hayan borrado la leyenda que me apareció de "found 2 high severity vulnerabilities". No se si alguien me pudiera orientar al respecto sobre esto, y si debo de preocuparme de esa leyenda ya que soy alguien nuevo en el mundo del NODE JS. Gracias.

Comment: Te está auditando las dependencias y te está diciendo que hay vulnerabilidades reportadas en algunas de ellas. Como eso es dinámico (y dependiendo de cómo definas tus dependencias), eso va a cambiar (porque usas la versión más reciente de algo y lo actualizan, porque actualizaste una versión en el package.json y esa ya no es vulnerable). Es una buena práctica controlar que no se usen dependencias con vulnerabilidades

Answer (score -1):

no sé si a estas alturas te sirve la respuesta, pero me pasó algo parecido y lo solucioné con lo siguiente:
Paso 1. Actualizar NPM con el comando:
npm install -g npm@latest
Paso 2. Borrar la cache de NPM:
npm cache clean --force
Paso 3. Desactivar las auditorias de NPM:
npm set audit false
Esta info la copié y pegué de la página:
https://victorroblesweb.es/2018/05/23/solucion-vulnerabilities-error-con-npm/

Comment: Pésima idea desactivar cosas sin más.

Comment: ¿Por qué desactivar las auditorías de NPM?